# Rebus and RabbitMQ - Use multiple independent instances of Rebus?

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, rebus

I got a Rebus Servicebus console application running as a windows service on my test environment. The servicebus is created like this:

```
Bus = Configure.With(adapter)
               .Logging(l => l.Log4Net())
               .Transport(
                    t => t.UseRabbitMq(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RabbitMQ.Url"],
                        ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RabbitMQ.Queue"],
                        ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RabbitMQ.ErrorQueue"])
                        .ManageSubscriptions())
               .MessageOwnership(d => d.FromRebusConfigurationSection())
               .Sagas(s => s.Use(new RavenDbSagaPersister(sagaDocumentStore)))
               .Timeouts(t => t.Use(new RavenDbTimeoutStorage(sagaDocumentStore)))
               .CreateBus().Start();
```

The appsettings looks like this:

```
<add key="RabbitMQ.Url" value="amqp://rabbitUser:password@localhost"/>
<add key="RabbitMQ.Queue" value="myFirstQueue"/>
<add key="RabbitMQ.ErrorQueue" value="myFirstQueue.error" />
```

As you can see it's talking to RabbitMQ @localhost.

So far so good, this works like a charm.

However, we need to setup another instance of the Servicebus on the same server(it's a testserver and we got multiple branches on it) and now I've run into some problems.

The appsettings for the second instance looks like this:

```
<add key="RabbitMQ.Url" value="amqp://rabbitUser:password@localhost"/>
<add key="RabbitMQ.Queue" value="mySecondQueue"/>
<add key="RabbitMQ.ErrorQueue" value="mySecondQueue.error" />
```

When I start sending messages to the first Service, I can see that they are also being picked up by the second service, I assume that this is because they are using the same RabbitMQ instance @localhost?

Im not an expert on servicebuses, I thought that just using different queues would get rid of this problem, but it didn't.

I've read something about virtual hosts, is that the way to go?

**WHAT I WANT TO DO:**

Send message to service1 -> Save into a specific database

Send message to service2 -> Save into another database

**What actually happens:**

Sends message to service1 -> service1 AND service2 picks them up and saves in both databases.

Could somebody please point me in the right direction? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve it using virtual hosts(vhost)

In RabbitMQ I added two virtual hosts, bus1 and bus2, I then gave my users permission to use them.

Then I changed the connectionstring to this and it worked like a charm :)

`<add key="RabbitMQ.Url" value="amqp://busUser2:password@localhost/bus2"/>`

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear from your question whether you `bus.Send` the message or `bus.Publish` the message - but since you're calling `ManageSubscriptions()` in your configuration, I assume the latter...?

Rebus has two basic ways of sending messages - you can `bus.Send` when you intend for one, specific recipient to get the message, or you can `bus.Publish` when you basically don't care who gets it :) (you *do* care of course, but you let the subscriber end of the relationship be the one that cares deeply enough to `bus.Subscribe` to the message type).

In your case, it sounds to me like you want to `bus.Send(yourMessage)` and then, in the sender's `app.config`, you specify [who owns the message type](https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/wiki/IDetermineMessageOwnership#whats-this-thing-about-owning-a-message) by mapping the type to `myFirstQueue`.

I hope it makes sense :) you should not need to mess around with virtual hosts and all kinds of funky Rabbit setup in order to make this work, it should be easy to do without any additional configuration.

Comment: I will have a look at this as well, right now Im using the virtual host solution because it was a quick fix, but this seems like a cleaner solution :)